# Parse twitter API to GEOJSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, geojson

I'me trying to parse the response from twitter api to create an output ready to GeoJSon.

but I can't retrieve the values to create my $features variable

```
$original_data = json_decode($response, true);
$features = array();
foreach($original_data as $tweet)
{
    $features[] = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'properties' => array(
                'NAME' => $tweet->text
        ),
        'geometry' => array(
                "type"=> "Point",
                "coordinates"=> array(
                    "todo",
                    "todo"
                )
        )
    );
}
$new_data = array(
    'type' => 'FeatureCollection',
    'features' => $features
);
```

$original_data output:

```
array(2) {
  ["statuses"]=>
  array(15) {
    [0]=>
    array(25) {
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(30) "Mon Jul 25 09:59:38 +0000 2016"
      ["id"]=>
      int(757515646938804225)
      ["id_str"]=>
      string(18) "757515646938804225"
      ["text"]=>
      string(117) "#wp_Dev #ajax #stackoverflow How to handle big integer numbers in JSON response in Javascript"
      ["truncated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["entities"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["hashtags"]=>
```

my output must be like this:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "NAME": "name"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    "todo",
                    "todo"
                ]
            }
        },
```

Comment: `foreach($original_data['statuses'] as $tweet)` to loop through each status

Comment: You've asked PHP to decode the JSON as an associative array (by passing `true` as the 2nd argument to `json_decode()`) so you can't use the arrow operator but instead must use square brackets like `$tweet['text']`

Comment: Great :D that works fine. Thanks!!!